# Is it possible to group controllers in sails using subfolders?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm planning to organize my controllers in sails using subfolder but I'm not sure how to do it. When I tried using like admin/PageController.js and connect it with the route I keep getting a 404 error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can definitely do this.  The trick is, the controller identity is its path, in your case `admin/PageController`.  So a custom route in `config/routes.js` would be something like:

```
'GET /admin/page/foo': 'admin/PageController.foo'
```

The great thing is, automatic actions still work, so if you have an `index` action in the controller then browsing to `/admin/page` will automatically run it.

You can also create controllers like this with `sails generate controller admin/page`.

Comment: Hello Scott, I've tried doing this but I'm getting a 404 error. When I run `sails lift --silly` I can't see the /admin/page/foo path. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I created a new app using `sails new` with rc3, then `sails generate controller admin/page foo`, and was able to lift and hit that route.  Maybe post a gist with your controller and routes.js file?

Comment: Thanks, I just pulled the latest version of 0.10 and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Note: You can also use the nested controller path name as a policy key. 

`config/policies.js` - 

`'admin/PageController' : {
'*': 'authorized',
'foo':'isFoo'
}`

Answer (score 9):

### **Edit**

Since [commit 8e57d61](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/commit/8e57d61ba1aa7755c886e8fb3fb893931b1b011e) you can do this to get `blueprint` routes and functionality on nested controllers, assuming there is an `AdminPage` model in your project:

```
// api/controllers/admin/PageController.js
module.exports = {
  _config: {
    model: 'adminpage'
  }
}
```

or this:

```
// config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  'admin/page': {
    model: 'adminpage'
  }
}
```

### **Old Answer**

**Your options**

1. Defining explicit routes to your grouped controllers in `config/routes.js`. 
   Look at Scott Gress' answer for more details.
2. (If you are a bit adventurous) As i had the exact same requirement for a project of mine I created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/1441) on Sails that allows you to override the model - controller association. You could install it via

   ```
   npm install -g git://github.com/marionebl/sails.git#override-controller-model
   ```

   Assuming it is the `api/models/Page.js` model you want the blueprint methods for on `api/controllers/admin/PageController.js` you then could do:

   ```
   // api/controllers/admin/PageController.js
   ...
   module.exports = {
     _config: {
       model: 'page'
     }
   }
   ```

**Explanation**

While generating/creating grouped controllers like this is perfectly valid an possible, you will not get the default blueprint routes you'd expect for controllers accompanied by models with the same identity.

E.g. `api/controllers/UserController.js` and `api/models/User.js` share the same identity `user`, thus the blueprint routes are mounted if they are enabled in `config/blueprints.js`.

In fact at the moment it is not possible to group models into subfolders in a valid way. This means you won't be able to create a model that matches the identity `admin/page` of your controller `api/controllers/admin/PageController.js` - the blueprint routes are not mounted for `PageController`.

The source responsible for this behavior [can be inspected on Github](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/index.js#L222).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, as per my experiment it will work with me fine.
routes.js

{ 
    controller: "admin/UserController", action: "find",
    model : 'user', //NOTE : Model name should be small letter
  },

Answer (score 6):

I made a diagram that shows how implicit routes, explicit policies, nested controllers, singular models and nested views are related. It does not show an overridden model-controller association as described by @marionebl.

It was mostly an exercise for me to understand this topic better, but I hope it helps somebody else too. Please let me know if I made any mistakes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for making a great product @mikermcneil !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks merionebl, its work fine for me and I want to share with all guys my answer derived from merionebl answer.

**/config/routes.js**

```
  'get /admin/user' : { 
    controller: "Admin/UserController", action: "find",
    model : 'user',
  },
```

My aim is not repeat answer just have upgrade and clear example.

Thanks