# Create subfolders in Sails.js /api/controllers

Tags: node.js, sails.js

here is my problem: I would like to create some subfolders inside /api/controllers in order to organize my source code. My problem there is that as soon as I create a new folder, blueprint api / routes / actions don't seem to work anymore.

From all my tests if I change /api/controller/UserController.js to /api/controller/newpath/UserController.js I can't get the beauty of blueprint working anymore.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks
Emmanuel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set this up. Its a bit undocumented, but you can setup a "_config" object on your controller

```
api/controllers/subFolder/YourController.js
...
module.exports = {
  _config: {
    model: 'YourModel' // case sensitive
    actions: true,
    shortcuts: true,
    rest: true
  }
}
```

Check out this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22062367/1821723

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it seems to be case sensitive, and 'YourModel' has to be written 'yourModel' !
I've spent several hours on this error. 
actions, shortcuts and rest config attributes are by default enabled.

Answer (score 7):

**Update January 2016**

Since version 0.10.0, you can definitely do this.

The controller identity is its path, in your case `newPath/UserController`.  So a custom route `config/routes.js` would be something like:

```
'GET /newPath/user': 'newPath/UserController'
```

Automatic actions still work. You can also create controllers like this with `sails generate controller newPath/user`.

Answer (score 1):

You can config routes.js as below

```
//application
'post /:api_key/applications'         : 'Threescale.Application.create',
'get /:api_key/check_api_key'         : 'Threescale.Application.check',
'get /:token/manager_list_accounts'   : 'Threescale.Account.list',
'put /:token/manager_approve_account' : 'Threescale.User.activate',
```

Under api/controllers, you can manage sub folders and actions as:

```
Threescale
    Application
        - create.js
        - check.js
    Account
        - list.js
    User
        - activate.js
```

Hope this is helpful for you!

Answer (score -2):

You're right.
It doesn't work out of the box though you can try this approach:

In you `models/User.js` set `identity: "newpath/user"`

Hope it helps!

Comment: doesn't work for me, it's on the controller side and not on the model side.
The route to access the controller is /newpath/modelName
In the NameController.js add the _config object, with mode attribute with the name of the model, in lower case