# Sails JS: I need my blueprints to be available under 2 different urls api/v1 and api/v1/admin, how?

Tags: sails.js

So, I am looking for a way, so that my blueprints are automatically available from two urls, api/v1 and api/v1/admin

Whats the best way to get this under Sails.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do it the exact same way you normally would for both folders (creating a controller that references the model in question) but use the _config key in your subfolder's controllers to specify the model

[Create subfolders in Sails.js /api/controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368946/create-subfolders-in-sails-js-api-controllers)