# Sails.js separate views and assets in project

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express, sails.js

I have a sails webpoject and i need to divide it logically in 2 groups:

1. site - the client side
2. admin - the cms

This two parts should share only part of js libraries i have in asserts folder. And they should have different layouts.

What is the correct way to separate them?

Answer (score 1):

Your going to find a lot of different answers here, but I might suggest just seperating the controllers and views into coorisponding subfolders.

```
api/controllers/cms/...*.js
views/cms/...*.ejs

api/controllers/site/...*.js
views/site/...*.ejs
```

Reference 
[Create subfolders in Sails.js /api/controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368946/create-subfolders-in-sails-js-api-controllers)

However, there are going to be lots of opinions here, you might consider google groups for a question like this
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sailsjs

Comment: Thank you @Meeker. Could you please, kindly answer in more detail, how should I write the routes then? How to divide asserts's scripts and styles?

Comment: You don't have to write your routes if you don't want to and assets can also be in their own sub directories as well. To be honest if you want more detail your probably better looking somewhere else, StackOverflow is better for concise answers, not full design treatments.

Comment: Thanks. but I actually need to add use routes for my controller. And I do not want a separate folders for controllers. The question is more about organizing assets and views. So I'll listen to your advice and repost this question in the Google Groups.

Comment: @AlexanderArutinyants, hi! I have the same problem here. Could you please tell me how did you resolve this? How did you share these two projects: CMS and Client in your `assets` folder? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @TurakVladyslav - If I remember well (it was a long time ago, so...) I kind of duplicated all the grunt tasks there... When you open the grunt files that build front-end you will see - it's pretty straight forward.