# using blueprints on Hierarchical APIs in Sails

Tags: sails.js

I've got a `models` folder (and corresponding `controllers` folder) that looks like this:

```
.
├── Pets
|   ├── User.js
│   └── Pet.js
└── UserManager
    ├── User.js
    ├── Group.js
    └── Organization.js
```

and would like to use REST blueprints of the type

`POST to foosite.com/userManager/user`

or at least

`POST to foosite.com/user`

Is there an easy way to do this?

Corresponding shortcut routes and action routes would also be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use controllers in subfolders and specify their corresponding model.

Currently models do not work in subfolders.

Check out this answers

[Create subfolders in Sails.js /api/controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368946/create-subfolders-in-sails-js-api-controllers)

[Is it possible to group controllers in sails using subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059833/is-it-possible-to-group-controllers-in-sails-using-subfolders/22062367#22062367)