# Is it possible to group services in sails using subfolders?

Tags: sails.js

Is it possible to group services files into subfolders under services in [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059833/is-it-possible-to-group-controllers-in-sails-using-subfolders/22062367#22062367) speaks about grouping controllers. How do I do the same for services?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

- services/

  - FooBar/

    - foo.js
    - bar.js
  - FooBarService.js

Your `FooBarService.js` should just require everything inside `FooBar/`

```
/**
 * FooBarService
 */

module.exports = {
    foo: require('FooBar/foo.js'),
    bar: require('FooBar/bar.js')
};
```

Or if you want to make it more sails-y, use [`include-all`](https://github.com/balderdashy/include-all). It is include in all sails projects, and is used everywhere in sails

```
/**
 * FooBarService
 */

module.exports = require('include-all')({
    dirname: __dirname + '/FooBar',
    filter: /.+\.js$/
});
```